# Special character in "entrée" cannot be displayed correctly if defined in a separate javascript file

Tags: javascript, json, encoding, special-characters

Example:

The following string is defined in a json.js file.

```
var test = "One complimentary entrée with the purchase of an entrée.";
```

It is included in an index.html file by

```
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="./json.js"></script>
```

When the string is displayed in UI, it shows up as

```
"One complimentary entr�e with the purchase of an entr�e."
```

But if string is defined directly in the index.html, then it is not a problem.

Can anyone suggest a solution on how to keep the text in the separate .js file?

Comment: I find it amusing the way everyone describes non-ASCII characters as “special”. There are 107361 Unicode characters; only 0.12% of those are also ASCII. It is the ASCII characters that are “special”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the included file is saved using the same encoding as the page.

If for example the page is saved as UTF-8, the included file will also be loaded as UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks, json.js is now re-saved using UTF-8 encoding by notepad and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the non-Latin character to an HTML entity, &eacute; or change all aspects your development system and code editors to parse all text characters as UTF8.

Comment: UTF-8 end-to-end is the best solution.

Comment: If you have to encode to go down an ASCII-only JSON pipe, you should use string literal escaping: `entr\u00E9e`. HTML-encoding isn't related to JSON and you generally don't want to be displaying text text strings as raw HTML (leads to XSS problems).